# Sqlite issues in in python: List index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

```
import sqlite3

def create_history(string1, r):
   db = sqlite3.connect(r)
   curr = db.cursor()

   db.execute('drop table if exists r')
   db.execute('create table r (symbol text, name text, datastartdate integer, \
   dataenddate integer)')
   for line in string1:
      value = line.strip().split(',')
      symbol = value[0]
      name = value[1]
      datastartdate = int(value[2])
      dataenddate = int(value[3])
      db.execute("insert into r values (?,?,?,?)", 
                 (symbol, name, datestartdate, dataenddate))
   db.commit()
   curr.close()
   db.close()
```

For this code I keep getting errors. For now I'm getting `list index out of range`. I'm trying to create a database using SQLite but I'm not really experienced with it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    # Used internally for debug sandbox under external interpreter
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 13, in create_history
builtins.IndexError: list index out of range
```

The data in the file which is string1 is

```
AFU-UN,ACUITY FOCUSED TTL TRUST UNITS,20050216,20090831
BCD,DIAMONDCORE LTD,20080213,20091030
BMT,BMONT SPLIT CORP COM STK NPV,20060418,20090805
HUG,HORIZONS BETAPRO COMEX GOLD ET,20091029,20091030
NAE-UN,NAL OIL & GAS TST TRUST UNITS,19960813,20091030
NXY,NEXEN INC COM NPV,19950112,20091030
SCC,SEARS CANADA INC COM NPV,19950112,20091030
YNG,YUKON-NEVADA GOLD COM NPV,20050419,20091030
```

This is information about stocks, with values in the following order:

```
Symbol
Name
DataStartdate
DataEnddate
```

The file that ends up being created is always filled with a bunch of nulls. These are also the parameters being used to work the function

```
create_history(open('sample_history'), 'history.db'))
```

The nulls are the biggest problem now.

Comment: Please include the *full traceback* of the error message.

Comment: Your error probably comes from the values in `string1`. You'll need to show us how you produce that value, as apparently you have lines that do not have 4 values after splitting on the comma.

Comment: This is the stuff in the string1 file
AFU-UN,ACUITY FOCUSED TTL TRUST UNITS,20050216,20090831
BCD,DIAMONDCORE LTD,20080213,20091030
BMT,BMONT SPLIT CORP COM STK NPV,20060418,20090805
HUG,HORIZONS BETAPRO COMEX GOLD ET,20091029,20091030
NAE-UN,NAL OIL & GAS TST TRUST UNITS,19960813,20091030
NXY,NEXEN INC COM NPV,19950112,20091030
SCC,SEARS CANADA INC COM NPV,19950112,20091030
YNG,YUKON-NEVADA GOLD COM NPV,20050419,20091030

Comment: its based on stocks. The stocks symbol, name, datastartdate, dataenddate. So the file does have 4 values.

Comment: You need to [edit] your post to add that information. Show us a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: If you are reading a file, show us how you are reading the file.

Comment: I just wanna know how to execute the file apparently I'm supposed to do a for loop like. For row in c.execute but I'm not sure how the for loop looks

Answer (score 0):

If `string1` is the entire file in a single string, then `for line in strings: …` will iterate over each character in the string. You need to split on newlines first:

```
for line in strings.split('\n'):
    …
```

But it's better to feed in an iterator over the input file, e.g.:

```
def create_history(input, …):
    …
    for line in input:
        # line has the trailing \n, so you need to strip() or something.
        …

create_history(open('file.csv'), …)
```

Better still, use Python's csv module:

```
def create_history(input, …):
    …
    for row in csv.reader(input):
        symbol = row[0]
        …
```